# Google Sheets highlight cells based on specific duplicates

Tags: google-sheets

To try and keep it short, I will have an occurrence of a name anywhere within Column A. If it is in between cells A21:A29, I want to highlight it if the name also exists anywhere between cells B11:B39.

If you are looking for extra information regarding what I am doing, I am assigning people to heat lanes for a competition and I need to make sure that if a competitor is also judging that they are not judging during the heat before, during, or after they are competing. Is it as "simple" as writing a macro that checks each heat? Not sure if there is a simpler way with conditional formatting or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**custom formula:**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A21:A29,B$11:B$39,1,0),)<>"",1))
```

[image: 6]

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I'm looking for!